# elastic search query with willcard and escape chars

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, query-string, ipv4

we use elasticsearch on freebsd 11.
We have a lot data ipv4, ipv6 format in table.

Clients want to search with wilcard.
for example

```
*192* -> no problem
*192.168.* -> no problem
*2001:db8* -> take error
*2001\:db8 -> take error....
```

I did not take correct data from elastic. Espacially ":" is very problem.

My system info  and results of query are

elastic info this

```
{
  "name": "WxaxEg6",
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid": "o-7IPcD3RjODelTyPYUBJw",
  "version": {
    "number": "5.6.8",
    "build_hash": "688ecce",
    "build_date": "2018-02-16T16:46:30.010Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "6.6.1"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

my test table is

```
{
  "ip_test2": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "ip_addr": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1549119687946",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "Aljv_81nQDKx3B3Fs2nVOA",
        "version": {
          "created": "5060899"
        },
        "provided_name": "ip_test2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

query 1:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["ip_addr"],
            "query": "*192.*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
       }
    }
}'
```

Result is

```
{"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards": 
{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits": 
{"total":255,"max_score":1.0,"hits": 
 ...:{"ip_addr": "192.168.1.4"}},
```

no problem.

query 2

```
 "query": "*2001*",
```

Result is

```
{"took":5,"timed_out":false,"_shards": 
{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits": 
{"total":100,"max_score":1.0,"hits": 
...:{"ip_addr": "2001:db8:100:0:2359:8a17:17c6:e316"}},
```

No problem.
Now Problem starting.
Query

```
"query": "*2001:*",
```

Result

```
"error":{"root_cause": 
[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"Failed to parse query 
[*2001:*]","index_uuid":"Aljv_81nQDKx3B3Fs2nVOA","index":"ip_test2"}]
```

Query

```
"query": "\"*2001:db*\"",
```

Result is **wrong** , there is a lot of data start with 2001:db8

```
"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards": 
{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits": 
{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Query is

```
"query": "\"*2001:db8*\"",
```

Result is **correct** , amazing....WHYYYY

```
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards": 
{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits": 
{"total":100,"max_score":1.8449252,
```

field type not ip , i don't understand different results.

can someone explain to me

**My Last Solution is**

```
{"from":0,"size":100,"sort":[{"start_time": 
{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],
"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"start_time": 
{"gte":1546678703407,"lte":1549270703407,"format":"epoch_millis"}}},
            {"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match": 
{"query":"2001:db","fields":["ip_dst_saddr"],"type":"phrase_prefix"}},
                       {"query_string":{"query":"*2001\\:db*","fields": 
["ip_dst_saddr"],"analyze_wildcard":true}}]}}]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the query

`"query": "*2001:*"` you need to escape the colon ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154190/how-to-search-pattern-with-colon-in-elasticsearch) for more example ) so try to use `"query": "*2001\\:*"`

Then for the other query, you can't use the wildcard character inside a phrase matching ( see [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/wildcards-search-in-exact-phrase-in-query-string-search/13883/3) for more details )

If you use the validate API on your query :

```
POST <your_index>/_validate/query?explain=true
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["ip_addr"],
            "query": "\"*2001:db*\"",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
       }
    }
}
```

you will see that this query is explained to

```
"explanations": [
    {
      "index": "<your_index>",
      "valid": true,
      "explanation": """ip_addr:"2001 db""""
    }
  ]
```

and `"query": "\"*2001:db8*\""` to

```
"explanations": [
    {
      "index": "test_so",
      "valid": true,
      "explanation": """ip_addr:"2001 db8""""
    }
  ]
```

So the query `"query": "\"*2001:db*\""` will match only document having token "2001" and "db" in the same order ( the full token "db", not "db8" or anything else )
and the query `"query": "\"*2001:db8*\""` will match any document containing "2001" and "db8" in the same order.

You should really use the IP datatype of elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Unfortunately, I did not design the database. Ip field had define text datatype.  Client wants to search with wildcard. sample " * 168 * " for "192.168.122.10". ipv4 no problem but ipv6 is problem. my last solution added.

Comment: you don't have access to the mapping? You could add a subfield with a ip datatype then run an "update by query" to recreate subfield on existing documents.